# jquery .remove use a variable as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable packet

```
var packet = ""
```

and overtime the user presses a button it adds the letter a to the variable

```
packet =  packet + "a"
```

it also places a div with the id of the variables value so i have 3 divs each with different ids

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="aaa"></div>
```

and then another button calls a function

```
function open() {
packet = packet - "a"
$('#'+packet).remove();
}
```

but when this function is called it doesn't remove the divs at all.
i want the divs to be removed in the order they were added. I have tried doing classes and having a dot instead of the # and i have tried just putting the variable there

I think i have done something wrong with how i use the selector?

Comment: How is `packet` defined initially?

Comment: var packet = "" I will add this to the question

Comment: You can't do subtraction with strings, what are you expecting `"" - "a"` to give?

Comment: `packet = packet + "a"`

Comment: oh ok how else will i count then... You can't use numbers as an id or class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace in your open function

```
packet = packet - "a"
```

With this :

```
packet = packet.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
packet = packet.substring(0, packet.length - 1)
```

Comment: so this goes in my open() function? and now the <div> with that id will disappear?

Comment: This replaces `packet = packet - 'a'`

Comment: ok it works, kind of... it deletes everything until one is left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `+` for string concatenation in JavaScript

```js
var packet = '';
$('#btn').click(function() {
  packet += 'a';
  $('#' + packet).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="aa">aa</div>
<div id="aaa">aaa</div>

<button id=btn>click</button>
```